# NoSuchMethodError when using spf4j

Tags: java, profiling, spf4j

I'm trying to use spf4j https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j

I've tagged my method with:

```
@JmxExport
@PerformanceMonitor(warnThresholdMillis=1, errorThresholdMillis=100, recorderSource = RecorderSourceInstance.Rs5m.class)
```

And I get exception on it:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.spf4j.perf.aspects.PerformanceMonitorAspect.aspectOf()Lorg/spf4j/perf/aspects/PerformanceMonitorAspect;
```

I'm starting application From Eclipse with JDK 1.7.0_55
-javaagent:depend/aspectj/1.8.6/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar and with `aop-ajc.xml` in `src/META-INF` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="org.spf4j.perf.aspects.PerformanceMonitorAspect" />
</aspects>
<weaver options="-verbose">
    <include within="com.*..*" />
</weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Also JMX Beans are not visible in VisualVM at this point. 
What am I doing wrong?

Also logged as issue here:
https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

This happens when PerformanceMonitorAspect is not being weaved by AspectJ

adding to include org..* for weaving which will include the lib aspects fixes the issue.

```
<weaver options="-verbose -debug -showWeaveInfo">
    <include within="com.example..*" />
    <include within="org..*" />
</weaver>
```

For more detail [see](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/issues/4)